# Azure Functions: Can a shared .csx use a nuget package?

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-functions

A .csx file inside an Azure Function can use a nuget package if it's listed in the function's project.json file. Ex:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what happens with shared .csx files that are placed under the Function App's root (i.e. not in a specific function)? Is there a way to introduce a nuget package at the App Function (root) level?

I've found a workaround in uploading the nuget package's dll to a shared bin folder as explained in the [Azure Functions C# developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies):

> Shared assemblies are shared across all functions within a function app. To reference a custom assembly, upload the assembly to your function app, such as in a bin folder in the function app root.

Is there a way to do this better so my code depends on the nuget package and not on a dll?

Comment: What do you do with those shared `.csx` files? `#load` from function body? If so, you can still reference NuGet from functions, right?

Comment: Yes, I #load the shared .csx from a function and the function's project.json specifies the nuget dependency but still I get a compilation error.

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting? do  you have proper using statements in your shared csx?

Comment: Just tried reproducing and found that I couldn't. Once the nuget dependency is correctly described at the function level, the issue goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual package references are managed in each function (i.e. there's no function app level set of package references), but when brought into your function by using the `#load` directive, shared CSX files become part of the same compilation unit, and are able to consume assembly/package references defined in your function. But you still need to manage those at the function level.

You can think of the `#load` behavior as a linked file in a regular C# project, where the file is brought in, but compiled within the context of the project. That applies to functions here.

Comment: Thank you. I've found that, as you're describing, if I correctly specify the nuget dependency at the function level, then the function will compile just fine even when the shared .csx makes use of the dependency.